# Microsoft Word - Automatic Table of Authorhsip

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, word-processing, writing

Is there a way to insert an automatic table of authorship? Similar to an automatic table of figures or a table of contents.

And what I mean by table of authorship:
Say there are three authors of a paper, author A, author B, author C.

So at the top of their paper would be a table with all of their sections and which they wrote:

1 - A
1.1 - A
1.2 - B
2 - C
2.1 - C
2.2 - B